# How to select a specific amount of rows before and after predefined values

Tags: r

I am trying to select relevant rows from a large time-series data set. The tricky bit is, that the needed rows are before and after certain values in a column.

```
# example data
x <- rnorm(100)
y <- rep(0,100)
y[c(13,44,80)] <- 1
y[c(20,34,92)] <- 2
df <- data.frame(x,y)
```

In this case the critical values are 1 and 2 in the `df$y` column. If, e.g., I want to select 2 rows before and 4 after `df$y==1` I can do:

```
ones<-which(df$y==1)
selection <- NULL
for (i in ones) {
  jj <- (i-2):(i+4)
  selection <- c(selection,jj)
}
df$selection <- 0
df$selection[selection] <- 1
```

This, arguably, scales poorly for more values. For `df$y==2` I would have to repeat with:

```
twos<-which(df$y==2)
selection <- NULL
for (i in twos) {
  jj <- (i-2):(i+4)
  selection <- c(selection,jj)
}
df$selection[selection] <- 2
```

Ideal scenario would be a function doing something similar to this imaginary function  `selector(data=df$y, values=c(1,2), before=2, after=5, afterafter = FALSE, beforebefore=FALSE)`, where `values` is fed with the critical values, `before` with the amount of rows to select before and correspondingly `after`.

Whereas, `afterafter` would allow for the possibility to go from certain rows until certain rows after the value, e.g. `after=5,afterafter=10` (same but going into the other direction with `afterafter`).

Any tips and suggestions are very welcome!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy enough with `rep` and its each argument.

```
df$y[rep(which(df$y == 2), each=7L) + -2:4] <- 2
```

Here, `rep` repeats the row indices that your criterion 7 times each (two before, the value, and four after, the L indicates that the argument should be an integer). Add values -2 through 4 to get these indices. Now, replace.

Note that for some comparisons, `==` will not be adequate due to numerical precision. See the SO post [why are these numbers not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal/9508558) for a detailed discussion of this topic. In these cases, you could use something like

```
which(abs(df$y - 2) < 0.001)
```

or whatever precision measure will work for your problem.