# How to create sub data frames for each row with data before and after a row

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, nested

I've got a data like below:

```
ex <- structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1502480763.554, 1502480763.554, 
1502480764.968, 1502480765.554, 1502480768.554, 1502480770.554, 
1502480773.519, 1502480775.72, 1502480777.43, 1502480778.278, 
1502480778.288, 1502480778.759, 1502480780.472, 1502480782.815, 
1502480785.521, 1502480785.531, 1502480785.707, 1502480787.639, 
1502480789.1, 1502480790.682, 1502480791.554, 1502480793.322, 
1502480794.363, 1502480795.923, 1502480799.239, 1502480800.27, 
1502480800.554, 1502480802.554, 1502480805.63, 1502480805.959, 
1502480807.327, 1502480809.554, 1502480809.564, 1502480810.554, 
1502480812.8, 1502480813.838, 1502480813.848, 1502480816.24, 
1502480816.24, 1502480835.56, 1502480838.576, 1502480848.384, 
1502480851.859, 1502480853.554, 1502480856.375, 1502480857.688, 
1502480905.554, 1502480910.554, 1502480910.945, 1502480911.816
), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), order = c(NA, 
NA, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, NA, NA, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, NA, NA, NA, 
3L, NA, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, NA, 5L, 5L, 5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, 7L, NA, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 
10L), cat = c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 99, 99, 1, 1, 1, 99, 
99, 21, 1, 1, 1, 94, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 94, 1, 1, 99, 99, 1, 
61, 10, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 16, 1, 1, 13, 94), var1 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L), var2 = c(NA, NA, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, NA, NA, 0.9, 
0.9, 0.9, 0.9, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5.3, 5.3, 5.3, 5.3, 5.3, NA, 
8.6, 8.6, 8.6, 14.5, 14.5, 14.5, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 7.4, NA, 
7.4, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 1.2, 4.6, 4.6, -4.1, -4.1), 
    var3 = c(NA, NA, 35.8, 59.3, 51.3, 57.3, 77.5, 82.4, 41.6, 
    NA, NA, 66.8, 53, 77.1, NA, NA, 55.8, 81.4, 45.8, 37.9, NA, 
    38.5, 32, 72, 46.9, 76.4, 76.9, 88, NA, 11.7, 49.4, NA, NA, 
    64.1, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 72.5, 77.7, 83.3, 96.4, 83.3, 95.3, 
    NA, 69.8, 78.9, NA, NA), var4 = c(NA, NA, 26.6, 24, 9.7, 
    12.7, 21, 12.7, 9.7, NA, NA, 14, 20.3, 25.6, NA, NA, 18.6, 
    25.3, 15.7, 10.7, NA, 12.8, 8, 41.9, 12.8, 8.5, 10.2, 14.3, 
    NA, 19.3, 40, NA, NA, 1.2, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 10, 21.9, 
    19, 42, 11.8, 18.4, NA, 33.5, 3.7, NA, NA), var5 = c(NA, 
    NA, 2.8, 5.2, 2.3, 4.4, -0.9, 0.3, -0.8, NA, NA, 1.3, 1.5, 
    5.2, NA, NA, -0.7, -0.9, -0.3, 2.8, NA, 0.3, 1.8, 5.3, -0.9, 
    4.9, 0.9, 4.8, NA, 1.6, -0.8, NA, NA, -0.7, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, 0.4, 0.4, 2.2, 4.2, 1.5, -0.1, NA, 0.3, 1.8, NA, NA), 
    var6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, 
    TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    TRUE, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -50L))
```

Within the same values of column `order` I need to create (for each row) two nested sub-dataframes - one with data before and one with data in this row and after. So let's take for example a block of data where `order == 1`:

```
ex %>% filter(order == 1) %>% print()

# A tibble: 6 x 9
  timestamp           order   cat  var1  var2  var3  var4   var5 var6 
  <dttm>              <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <lgl>
1 2017-08-11 19:46:04     1     1     1   2.5  35.8  26.6  2.8   NA   
2 2017-08-11 19:46:05     1     1     1   2.5  59.3  24    5.20  NA   
3 2017-08-11 19:46:08     1     1     1   2.5  51.3   9.7  2.3   NA   
4 2017-08-11 19:46:10     1     1     1   2.5  57.3  12.7  4.40  TRUE 
5 2017-08-11 19:46:13     1     1     1   2.5  77.5  21   -0.9   NA   
6 2017-08-11 19:46:15     1     1     0   2.5  82.4  12.7  0.300 NA
```

I need two additional columns with nested data frames: `data_before` and `data_after`. For first row `data_before` would be empty and `data_after` would contain all the rows. For second row, `data_before` would contain only first row and `data_after` would contain rows from 2 to 6. For third row, `data_before` would contain first two rows and `data_after` would contains rows from 3 to 6 and so on... Such an operation need to be performed for every value of `order` in original data frame. How it can be accomplished?

Expected output for one block of data (with `order == 1`) would be:

```
structure(list(order = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), data_before = list(
    structure(list(), .Names = character(0), row.names = integer(0), class = "data.frame"), 
    structure(list(timestamp = structure(1502480764.968, class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = 1, var1 = 1L, var2 = 2.5, 
        var3 = 35.8, var4 = 26.6, var5 = 2.8, var6 = NA), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)), structure(list(
        timestamp = structure(c(1502480764.968, 1502480765.554
        ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = c(1, 
        1), var1 = c(1L, 1L), var2 = c(2.5, 2.5), var3 = c(35.8, 
        59.3), var4 = c(26.6, 24), var5 = c(2.8, 5.2), var6 = c(NA, 
        NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -2L)), structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1502480764.968, 
    1502480765.554, 1502480768.554), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), cat = c(1, 1, 1), var1 = c(1L, 1L, 1L), 
        var2 = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5), var3 = c(35.8, 59.3, 51.3), 
        var4 = c(26.6, 24, 9.7), var5 = c(2.8, 5.2, 2.3), var6 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
    -3L)), structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1502480764.968, 
    1502480765.554, 1502480768.554, 1502480770.554), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = c(1, 1, 1, 1), var1 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L), var2 = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), var3 = c(35.8, 
    59.3, 51.3, 57.3), var4 = c(26.6, 24, 9.7, 12.7), var5 = c(2.8, 
    5.2, 2.3, 4.4), var6 = c(NA, NA, NA, TRUE)), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L)), structure(list(
        timestamp = structure(c(1502480764.968, 1502480765.554, 
        1502480768.554, 1502480770.554, 1502480773.519), class = c("POSIXct", 
        "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), var1 = c(1L, 
        1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), var2 = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), var3 = c(35.8, 
        59.3, 51.3, 57.3, 77.5), var4 = c(26.6, 24, 9.7, 12.7, 
        21), var5 = c(2.8, 5.2, 2.3, 4.4, -0.9), var6 = c(NA, 
        NA, NA, TRUE, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ), row.names = c(NA, -5L))), data_after = list(structure(list(
    timestamp = structure(c(1502480764.968, 1502480765.554, 1502480768.554, 
    1502480770.554, 1502480773.519, 1502480775.72), class = c("POSIXct", 
    "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), var1 = c(1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L), var2 = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5
    ), var3 = c(35.8, 59.3, 51.3, 57.3, 77.5, 82.4), var4 = c(26.6, 
    24, 9.7, 12.7, 21, 12.7), var5 = c(2.8, 5.2, 2.3, 4.4, -0.9, 
    0.3), var6 = c(NA, NA, NA, TRUE, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L)), structure(list(
    timestamp = structure(c(1502480765.554, 1502480768.554, 1502480770.554, 
    1502480773.519, 1502480775.72), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
    ), tzone = "UTC"), cat = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1), var1 = c(1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 0L), var2 = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), var3 = c(59.3, 
    51.3, 57.3, 77.5, 82.4), var4 = c(24, 9.7, 12.7, 21, 12.7
    ), var5 = c(5.2, 2.3, 4.4, -0.9, 0.3), var6 = c(NA, NA, TRUE, 
    NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-5L)), structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1502480768.554, 
1502480770.554, 1502480773.519, 1502480775.72), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = c(1, 1, 1, 1), var1 = c(1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L), var2 = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5, 2.5), var3 = c(51.3, 57.3, 
77.5, 82.4), var4 = c(9.7, 12.7, 21, 12.7), var5 = c(2.3, 4.4, 
-0.9, 0.3), var6 = c(NA, TRUE, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -4L)), structure(list(
    timestamp = structure(c(1502480770.554, 1502480773.519, 1502480775.72
    ), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = c(1, 
    1, 1), var1 = c(1L, 1L, 0L), var2 = c(2.5, 2.5, 2.5), var3 = c(57.3, 
    77.5, 82.4), var4 = c(12.7, 21, 12.7), var5 = c(4.4, -0.9, 
    0.3), var6 = c(TRUE, NA, NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", 
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L)), structure(list(timestamp = structure(c(1502480773.519, 
1502480775.72), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), 
    cat = c(1, 1), var1 = 1:0, var2 = c(2.5, 2.5), var3 = c(77.5, 
    82.4), var4 = c(21, 12.7), var5 = c(-0.9, 0.3), var6 = c(NA, 
    NA)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L)), structure(list(timestamp = structure(1502480775.72, class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC"), cat = 1, var1 = 0L, var2 = 2.5, var3 = 82.4, 
    var4 = 12.7, var5 = 0.3, var6 = NA), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -1L)))), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -6L))
```

Comment: Yes, I mean row numbers which are shown on the left. I'll try to make an expected output by hand.

Comment: Edited with expected output for one block of data.

Comment: Do you want `NA`s in `order` column to be ignored?

Comment: Yes. `NA`s should be left in a data, but no calculations is needed for them so they can have `NA`s as well in the `data_before` and `data_after` columns.

Comment: This [recent post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55550167/how-to-select-a-specific-amount-of-rows-before-and-after-predefined-values/55550288#55550288) may be useful.

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
library(tidyverse)

slice_dataframe <- function(r, ord = 1) {
    tibble("order" = ord,
           "data_before" = list(slice(ex, row_number() <= (r - ord))),
           "data_after"  = list(slice(ex, row_number() >= (r + ord))))
}

map_df(1:nrow(ex), slice_dataframe)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
ex.list <- lapply(split(ex, ex$order), function(x){
  ex.x <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, 
          lapply(1:nrow(x), function(i){
            c(x$order[i], ifelse(i==1, list(data.frame()), list(x[1:(i-1), ])), list(x[i:nrow(x), ]))
          })
  ))
  names(ex.x) <- c('order', 'data_before', 'data_after')
  ex.x
})
```

**Edit:**
Trying to give some more explanation to the code posted before:

```
# lapply() applies a function (input arg 2) to each element of a list (input arg 1) 
# and returns a list of return values of the function applied on each input element
ex.list <- lapply( 
  # the split() function returns a list of data.frames, subsets of ex 
  # splitted by ex$order; these will be the input for the 1. lapply() call
  split(ex, ex$order),
  # the following function will be applied to each of these data.farmes 
  # to create the return values 
  function(x){ # 'x' will be a data.frame, subset ox 'ex' with one single value of ex$order
    list.of.rows <- lapply(# we now loop over each row in the data.frame 
                           # containing data with one single value of ex$order, 
                           # 'i' is the row number
                           1:nrow(x), 
                           # the functions will create 1 row for the resulting data.frame
                           function(i){ 
                             c(# the row is 1 vector containing the following 3 values
                               # the first column of the putput data.frame is the value of ex$order
                               x$order[i], 
                               # the value for row i of data_before
                               ifelse(i==1, list(data.frame()), list(x[1:(i-1), ])), # for the first row we return an empty list, else the data.frame with previous (1:(i-1)) rows
                               # the values for row i of data_after
                               list(x[i:nrow(x), ]) # subset of rows as off row i
                               )
                             })
  # now that we have a list (list.of.rows) that contains one row for the output data.frame
  # we rbind these into one data.frame
  ex.x <- as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, # do.call(rbind, ...) cobines elements of ... using rbind()
                                list.of.rows 
  ))
  names(ex.x) <- c('order', 'data_before', 'data_after') # give column names to the output data.frame
  ex.x # define the return value of the function of the 1. lapply() call
})
```

Comment: Could you explain a little of what's going on in the code? It's fairly dense and I'm having a hard time teasing the steps out

Answer (score 0):

Using `tidyverse` we can split on `order` and for each dataframe create two new columns `data_before` and `data_after` which would contain a list of dataframes based on the conditions.

```
library(tidyverse)

ex %>%
  group_split(order) %>%
  map_dfr(. %>% 
       mutate(data_before = map(seq_len(nrow(.)), function(y) .[seq_len(y - 1), ]), 
              data_after = map(seq_len(nrow(.)), function(y) 
                         if (y == nrow(.)) .[0,] else .[(y + 1):nrow(.), ]))) %>%
  select(order, data_before, data_after)


# A tibble: 50 x 3
#   order data_before      data_after      
#   <int> <list>           <list>          
# 1     1 <tibble [0 × 9]> <tibble [5 × 9]>
# 2     1 <tibble [1 × 9]> <tibble [4 × 9]>
# 3     1 <tibble [2 × 9]> <tibble [3 × 9]>
# 4     1 <tibble [3 × 9]> <tibble [2 × 9]>
# 5     1 <tibble [4 × 9]> <tibble [1 × 9]>
# 6     1 <tibble [5 × 9]> <tibble [0 × 9]>
# 7     2 <tibble [0 × 9]> <tibble [3 × 9]>
# 8     2 <tibble [1 × 9]> <tibble [2 × 9]>
# 9     2 <tibble [2 × 9]> <tibble [1 × 9]>
#10     2 <tibble [3 × 9]> <tibble [0 × 9]>
# … with 40 more rows
```

---

This can also be translated in base R in the following way

```
do.call(rbind, lapply(split(ex, ex$order), function(x) {
     x$data_before <- lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(y) x[seq_len(y - 1), ])
     x$data_after <-  lapply(seq_len(nrow(x)), function(y) 
                       if (y == nrow(x)) x[0,] else x[(y + 1):nrow(x), ])
     x
}))
```